# Write to a serial port like with pythons serial lib

Tags: c#, python, serial-port

I used pythons [serial](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/url_handlers.html?highlight=serial#module-serial) lib to write commands to a usb port:

```
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = 'com4'
ser.baudrate = 115200
ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE
ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
ser.timeout = None
ser.open()
CMD_MOTOR_DRIVE=[1, 249, 3, 6, 42, 100]
ser.write(CMD_MOTOR_DRIVE_1)
```

Now I wants to do the same in c# with help of the [SerialPort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms143551(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
SerialPort port = new SerialPort();
port.PortName = ports[0]; //"com4"
port.BaudRate = 115200;
port.Parity = Parity.None;
port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
port.DataBits = 8;
port.Open();
//System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
if(port.IsOpen == true)
{
   log.Info("Port has been opened");
}
while(true)
{
   port.Write("1, 249, 3, 6, 11, 100");
}
```

I am able to open the port, but the controller seems not to response to the command of the port.Write(string) function. I do not know what is the corresponding way in c# to convert the command into a byte array. I think I have to use the port.Write((Byte[], Int32, Int32)) function and not the port.Write(string) one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier as expected:

```
byte[] a = { 1, 249, 3, 6, 11, 100 };
port.Write(a, 0, 6);
```